# line breaks in an input tag, data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, input, nl2br

My `<input>` tag is printing `<br />` instead of actually producing linebreaks? I have a  feeling it is something simple I have overlooked...

I should not that the `$bio` variable is being called from MySQL database, and is set to 'longtext'
(I suspect this might be playing a factor)

```
 <form>
<input 
style="position:relative;left:10px;min-height:270px;width:40%;border:solid 2px black;top:20px;"
type="text" 
name="bio" 
value ="<?php echo nl2br($bio);?>"
readonly="readonly" 
/>
 </form>
```

The output does in-fact show  `<br/>`

however my php does't seem to be converting it to actual line breaks.

Could anyone think of a reason this would be happening? (the only thing I thought of was checking for `htmlspecialchars()`, but there is none for the `$bio` variable.

Thanks!!

Comment: "however my php does't seem to be converting it to actual line breaks." How would you show line breaks in a text input field?

Comment: Why are you trying to end up with `<br/>`s inside of a text `input`'s `value`?

Comment: I want to have an `<input>` that displays paragraph's of information, let's say. So I'm trying to have linebreaks in the text. Right now they are only showing up as `<br />` in the text, not **actual** line-breaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular `input` tags the browser won't display new line chars.

You could use `textarea` if you need to display editable text.

Comment: Can these be posted to forms though? ( I will edit my post and put a `<form>` in if that was unclear)

Comment: The `textarea` works just like an `input` and it is sent in the form. Checkout some info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help! I though it was gonna be something simple.